# Calling an Insertion Sort from a main function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to do an insertion sort of a list of ten numbers, but I am supposed to do it from a main function. If I build a function for the insertion sort, how would I call it from a main function?

I have built an insertion sort function with the list at the bottom of the program. I don't know how to call the sort function from within a main function. I got mixed up and it's a mess now.

```
def main():
    aList =(29,23,19,6,26,16,12,27,3)
    unsortedList = sort_asc(aList)
    return unsortedList(mySortedList)
def sort_asc(aList):
    for index in range (1,len(aList)):
        value = aList[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0 and (value < aList[i]):
            aList[i+1] = aList[i]
            aList[i] = value
            i = i - 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I really don't know what I am doing and have not been able to find any relevant information to point me in the right direction, so I tried what I thought would work but ended up with this. Line 3, Line 10, Line 15 was referenced in my error message. "Tuple object does not support object assignment."

Comment: `aList =[29,23,19,6,26,16,12,27,3]` is a list `aList =(29,23,19,6,26,16,12,27,3)` is a tuple also you can call `sort_asc(aList)` from within `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: And tuples are immutable, meaning you can't assign new values to its elements. hense the error message.

Comment: I am an idiot and I solved it. sorry I was panicked and hellbent on finding the solution. Once I slowed down and took a break I got it right.

Comment: No problem @25toLeif I have tried to summarize the points made in an answer above, you can take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somme issues in your code

- `aList =(29,23,19,6,26,16,12,27,3)` declares a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) (declared with `()` brackets), which are immutable, i.e. they cannot be modified in-place, what you want is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), (declared with `[]` brackets), which is mutable and hence can be modified in-place
- You want to call your function from within `if __name__ == '__main__':` and you want to return a value from the function
- `unsortedList(mySortedList)` will actually call a function `unsortedList` with arguments `mySortedList`, and neither of them exist in your case

So fixing the issues above, the updated code looks like

```
def sort_asc(aList):
    for index in range (1,len(aList)):
        value = aList[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0 and (value < aList[i]):
            aList[i+1] = aList[i]
            aList[i] = value
            i = i - 1

    #Return the sorted list
    return aList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Declare a list
    aList = [29, 23, 19, 6, 26, 16, 12, 27, 3]
    #Call the function and print the result
    print(sort_asc(aList))
```

And the output will be

```
[3, 6, 12, 16, 19, 23, 26, 27, 29]
```